# Unable to initialize helm (tiller) on newly created GKE cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I have just created a GKE cluster on Google Cloud platform. I have installed in the cloud console `helm` :

```
$ helm version
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.0.0", GitCommit:"e29ce2a54e96cd02ccfce88bee4f58bb6e2a28b6", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.4"}
```

I have also created the necessary `serviceaccount` and `clusterrolebinding` objects:

```
$ cat helm-rbac.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: tiller
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: tiller
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: tiller
    namespace: kube-system


$ kubectl apply -f helm-rbac.yaml                                                                    

serviceaccount/tiller created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/tiller created
```

However trying to initialise `tiller` gives me the following error:

```
$ helm init --service-account tiller --history-max 300
Error: unknown flag: --service-account
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> However trying to initialise tiller gives me the following error:
>
> Error: unknown flag: --service-account
>
> Why is that?

[Helm **3** is a major upgrade](https://helm.sh/blog/helm-3-released/). The **Tiller** component is now obsolete.

There is no command `helm init` therefore also the flag `--service-account` is removed.

> The internal implementation of Helm 3 has changed considerably from Helm 2. The most apparent change is the **removal of Tiller**.